# In QGIS for Type Case in Labels, Rule Based Rule, the Capitalize first letter option does not work

Tags: qgis, labeling, expression

Here are my labels untouched

[image]

Now when i change to all lowercase

[image]

You see that it changes

[image]

However for type case i want to capitalize first letter

[image]

It shows that it made it everything capitalized

[image]

The default lettering of the values are all capital.

I tried the expression below. "Street" is the name of the field. It even acknowledged the output preview and changed it how i would have liked to ideally.

```
title("Street")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A reasonable person might expect the setting "Capitalize first letter" to convert the label to title case.

- lower case
- UPPER CASE
- Title Case (first letter of each word capitalized, remaining letters lowercase)

However, it seems that "Capitalize first letter" does *exactly* what it says, and no more. It doesn't change the other letters to lowercase.

[image]

This isn't technically a bug. But it will definitely confuse many QGIS users. I suggest making a [feature request](https://issues.qgis.org) to add title case as an option. It will be low priority, but it seems easy to implement, so it may not take too long.

---

The current workaround, as you discovered, is to use the `title()` function.

[image]